# Have I mismanaged a promise? or mismanaged a data type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, async-await

I would love to hear some ideas to solve this problem. Here's a javascript function. Make note of the comments, I'll refer to those specific lines later.

```
async function getGroupId(name) {
    const response = await fetch(
        environmentData.localFunctionsUrl + functionPath,
        {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                command: `GetInterests`,
                path: `/interest-categories/`
        }),
        method: `POST`
        }
    )
    const groupId = await response.json().then((json) => {
        return json.map((obj) => {
            if(obj.name.substring(0, `YYYY-MM-DD`.length) === name.substring(0, `YYYY-MM-DD`.length)) {
                return obj.id //LET'S CALL THIS LINE "yellow"
            }
        })[0] //AND THIS LINE, LET'S CALL IT "yellow-ish"
    })
    const retObj = { [groupId]: true } //LET'S CALL THIS LINE "orange"
    return retObj
}
```

That function is called in my code like this:

```
async function registerSubscriber(data) {
    const emailToHash = data.paymentIntent.metadata.contact_email
    const response = await fetch(
        environmentData.localFunctionsUrl + functionPath,
        {
            body: JSON.stringify({
                command: `UpsertMember`,
                path: `/members/`+ crypto.createHash(`md5`).update(emailToHash.toLowerCase()).digest(`hex`),
                mailchimp_body: {
                    email_address: emailToHash,
                    merge_fields: {
                        COURSEDATE: data.paymentIntent.metadata.courseData_attr_name.substring(
                            0,
                            data.paymentIntent.metadata.courseData_attr_name.indexOf(`:`)
                            ),
                        FNAME: data.paymentIntent.metadata.contact_firstname,
                        LNAME: data.paymentIntent.metadata.contact_surname
                    },
// HERE: NEXT LINE
                    interests: await getGroupId(data.paymentIntent.metadata.courseData_attr_name)
                }
            }),
        method: `PATCH`
        }
    )
    const json = await response.json()
    return json
}
```

So, THIS ALL WORKS in my local environment. This code properly interacts with a lambda function I've created to interact with MailChimp's API.

**Here's the problem:** in my production environment (Netlify, fyi), line "yellow" is reached (a match is made in the `if` statement), so presumably there's an element available in line "yellow-ish".

But certainly **`groupId` in line "orange" is undefined.**

#### Theory 1:

My working theory is it's failing due to race-condition. I mean, perhaps line "orange" is being returned before line "yellow" produces the relevant data. But I'm (almost) certain I've structured the promises correctly -- the `async` and `await` keywords

#### Theory 2:

My other working theory is that I've mismanaged the data types. Is there a reason that `{[groupId]:true}` may work in a windows environment but not in a linux env (both env's running the same version of node).

Related to this theory: the value returned in line "yellow" sometimes begins with a number, sometimes with a letter. This *shouldn't* matter, but I mention it because line "orange" will sometimes like like this:

`{ '123abc': true }`

And sometimes without quotes like this:

`{ abc123: true }`

I presume this difference in syntax is a known behaviour in Javascript -- is it just how object keys are handled?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the asynchrony in your code. There's better ways than using `map`+`[0]` or `.then()`, but the code should work as expected. The culprit is much more likely the return value of the request. Please post the value of `json` that you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that caught my attention was the `map` inside the following method:

```js
const groupId = await response.json().then((json) => {
  return json.map((obj) => {
    if(obj.name.substring(0, `YYYY-MM-DD`.length) === name.substring(0, `YYYY-MM-DD`.length)) {
      return obj.id //LET'S CALL THIS LINE "yellow"
    }
  })[0] //AND THIS LINE, LET'S CALL IT "yellow-ish"
})
```

While this could provide you with the value you're looking for, it's generally bad practice, because a `map` would loop through the whole array and it'll replace each value of the array that doesn't match your conditions with `undefined`, so if the value you're looking for is not at index `0` then you'll most certainly get `undefined` when you run the method. The method you need is `find` which will get a value/object out of the array and make it directly accessible.

Try the following code:

```js
async function getGroupId(name) {
  const response = await fetch(
    environmentData.localFunctionsUrl + functionPath,
    {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        command: `GetInterests`,
        path: `/interest-categories/`
      }),
      method: `POST`
    }
  );
  const responseJson = await response.json();
  const group = responseJson.find(obj => obj.name.substring(0, `YYYY-MM-DD`.length) === name.substring(0, `YYYY-MM-DD`.length));
  return {
    [group.id]: true
  };
}

async function registerSubscriber(data) {
  const {
    paymentIntent: {
      metadata: {
        contact_email,
        courseData_attr_name,
        contact_firstname,
        contact_surname
      }
    }
  } = data;
  const interests = await getGroupId(courseData_attr_name);
  const response = await fetch(
    environmentData.localFunctionsUrl + functionPath,
    {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        command: 'UpsertMember',
        path: `/members/${crypto.createHash(`md5`).update(contact_email.toLowerCase()).digest(`hex`)}`,
        mailchimp_body: {
          email_address: contact_email,
          merge_fields: {
            COURSEDATE: courseData_attr_name.substring(0, courseData_attr_name.indexOf(`:`)),
            FNAME: contact_firstname,
            LNAME: contact_surname
          },
          interests
        }
      }),
      method: 'PATCH'
    }
  );
  const json = await response.json();
  return json
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't say for certain if your handling of the JSON response is wrong without any sample (dummy) data, but usually a JSON object is not an array, so you can't handle it with a `map`.

Side note, you should try to stick to either async/await or `then/catch`.

Comment: There's no problem with using `await` in the arguments of a function call. Sure, a separate variable for `interests` is cleaner, but the OP's style works as well.

Comment: @Bergi good point, thanks! I've amended my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: @V.Dimitrov's comments about .map() was most helpful. Thank you! I know precisely what I was doing wrong.

I knew .map() would produce a new array. BUT I hadn't realized that .map() would produce undefined elements if the mapping function had no return value.

So: notice my line `return obj.id` after the `if` statement. I thought _that_ would be the only element produced in the array. That's why I then used the first element `[0]` — I incorrectly had full confidence that my code produced a new array with a length of `1`. I should have checked the length of the new array.

Mystery solved!

Comment: Thanks also to @Bergi. Your comments also certainly helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your should work well, If you get `groupId` undefined then `json.map((obj) => {...}` returns empty array.
Try to debug or add console.log:

```
const groupId = await response.json().then((json) => {
    console.log('server response', json);
    return json.map((obj) => {
        if(obj.name.substring(0, `YYYY-MM-DD`.length) === name.substring(0, `YYYY-MM-DD`.length)) {
            return obj.id //LET'S CALL THIS LINE "yellow"
        }
    })[0] //AND THIS LINE, LET'S CALL IT "yellow-ish"
})
console.log('groupId', groupId);
const retObj = { [groupId]: true } //LET'S CALL THIS LINE "orange"
return retObj
```

PS: As mentioned in other comments you should stick to await or then and not try to mix them

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'll refactor the code to use .then() and .catch() in future. I agree it's a better pattern.